# Django: how to attach a pdf file to a model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Update: Below is good code but I happened to have a user error as I was trying to test it. So I asked a question not understanding I had an accurate answer. @yuri comments were helpful. I couldn't find a guide anywhere as simple as the recipe laid out below, instead working through 4 different django documentation pages. I hope others will find the below code helpful.

---

I would like to be able to attach a file to a model object in the django shell. So far, I think I have set up the necessary parts. In my settings file:

```
from unipath import Path
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",
)
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)  # settings.py in settings dir
MEDIA_DIR = (PROJECT_DIR.child("media"))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My model:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
press_release_storage = FileSystemStorage()

class Peer(models.Model):
    peer_quarter_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    press_release = models.FileField(
        upload_to='press_releases',
        storage=press_release_storage,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

Then in the `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from peer.models import Peer
>>> from django.core.files import File
>>>
>>> peer = Peer.objects.create(peer_quarter_code='20133ABC')
>>> content = File(open('20133ABC_pr.pdf'))  # conveniently placed
>>> peer.press_release = content
>>> peer.save()
>>> type(peer.press_release)
<class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile'>
>>>
>>> peer.press_release.save('20133ABC_pr.pdf', content, save=True)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Although I have experience with Django, this code reflects the first time I have worked with `File`, `FileSystemStorage`, `FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS`, etc. Whatever guidance I might get, some clear explanation of the steps would be very valuable.

UPDATE: I just re-ran the code used at the console, and did not get the `AttributeError`. PEBKAC I guess. However, the file has not been saved into the `media` directory, which is what I expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why did you decide to use the django `File` object instead of a normal one? (A normal python file object has an attribute called size. That's missing according to the error)

Comment: @yuri I thought I was following django directions.

Comment: @yuri I tried that but when I try `peer.press_release.save('20133ABC_pr.pdf`, open('20133ABC_pr.pdf`), save=True)` I get `Attribute Error: 'file' object has no attribute 'save'. So I don't know yet what I am doing correctly or incorrectly here.

Comment: Actually I just tested your code and had zero problems with it. Are you sure you have the right filename? (Maybe try using the absolute path for it?)

Comment: Thanks @yuri. I was looking for files in my `media` dir, but instead they were in a stand-alone `press_release` dir. Once I saw that, I came to the same conclusion which is my code worked. Thanks for looking over my shoulder. The was a brand new use of Django for me.